# Exibir MySQL dentro de modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo um novo sistema de pedidos em PHP que funciona da seguinte maneira:

- O usuário faz *upload* dos pedidos, que são armazenados em uma tabela MySQL chamada *pedidos*;
- Após o upload, o usuário pode alterar o *status* desses pedidos importados, através de *script* no PHP que fazem o UPDATE da tabela *pedidos*;
- Cada alteração é salva através de um *trigger* em uma tabela chamada *logs*;
- Os pedidos possuem um número único e exclusivo que não se repete.

Eu conseguiria criar um *link* no número do pedido, por exemplo, que invoca um modal, e dentro deste modal exibir as alterações que estão na tabela *logs* somente daquele número de pedido clicado?

*exibição dos dados do MySQL na pagina:*

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos`");

    echo "<div style='height: 70%;'><table border='1' id='pedidos' class='table table-responsive'>
    <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
    <th>Data de emissão</th>
    <th>EMS</th>
    <th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Valor do pedido</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Nota Fiscal</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "</ul>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><a data-toggle='modal' href='#myModal'>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</a></td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['NrPedido'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form></div>";
```

Fiz a seguinte query para trazer o pedido pelo numero do pedido:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `logs` where nPedido IN (34366)");
```

Porém, não sei como substituir o numero do pedido que esta definido na *query* pelo numero de pedido clicado.

Comment: Sim, conseguiria. Mas para te ajudar nisso nós precisaremos de mais informações: como estes registros estão sendo exibidos com PHP? Qual é a estrutura do HTML para isso? Você sabe trabalhar com modais? Você sabe como funciona requisições AJAX?

Comment: Olá Anderson! Adicionei ina pergunta como os dados são exibidos na pagina! Com os modais li a documentação do bootstrap, e não me parece muito complexo. Agora em relação ao AJAX, sei que ele possibilita fazer requisições, tanto de scripts quanto de PHP, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer o script php para puxar os dados.

Comment: Rick, eu não estou com tempo de elaborar uma resposta agora, mas fiz um exemplo funcional ([link](https://jsbin.com/wogufug/edit?html,output)). Veja se consegue entender como funciona. Eu elaboro a resposta assim que possível, caso ninguém responda antes.

Comment: Anderson, obrigado pelo exemplo. Li um pouco mais sobre ajax e como ele manipula os dados. Li mais um pouco e adicionei o codigo a pagina, e dentro da div do modal, coloquei as colunas, que exibem as alterações. Mas não sei como definir o nPedido conforme o  usuario clicar. (O atual fica fixo na query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível e é simples. Pra isso você utilizará a função `$.ajax()` do jQuery.

1 - crie um lista dos produtos do banco de dados e link o ID de cada produto em um link, algo como:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos`");

        echo "<div style='height: 70%;'><table border='1' id='pedidos' class='table table-responsive'>
        <tr>
        <th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
        <th>Data de emissão</th>
        <th>EMS</th>
        <th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Valor do pedido</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Nota Fiscal</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo "</ul>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td><a id='ver_pedido' data-ref=".$row['nPedido']." href='javascript:void(0)'>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</a></td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['NrPedido'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form></div>";
```

2 - Obtenha o ID do link clicado:

**jQuery**

```
$('a#ver_pedido').click(function(){

    let id_pedido = $(this).attr('data-ref');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pagina_detalhada.php',
        data: {id: id_pedido},
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(response){

            $('#div_dentro_modal').empty();
            $('#div_dentro_modal').html(response);
            $('#abremodal').click();
        }
    });
});
```

3 - Crie um link com as configurações para abrir o modal (pode colocar esse link em qualquer parte do HTML menos em loops do PHP):

```
<a data-toggle='modal' id="abremodal" href='#myModal'></a>
```

4 - Dentro do seu modal, crie uma div e coloque a mesma ID que você colocou na função `success` do jQuery, no meu caso:

```
<div id="div_dentro_modal"></div>
```

5 - Crie a página que você passou no parâmetro `url` do `$.ajax()` e nele, pegue a ID do pedido clicado e monte um HTML para exibir no modal, algo como:

**pagina_detalhada.php**

```
<?php
$id_pedido = $_POST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `logs` where nPedido IN ('".$id_pedido."')");

//.... Restante do código, após obter o resultado de um "echo" para enviar ao modal
```

**OBS: não esqueça do passo 4, ele é muito importante para exibir as informações no modal**

Comment: Só um detalhe: id deve ser único na página, não faz sentido definir um elemento com id dentro de um while. Ideal seria utilizar classes.

Comment: Olá Alisson, seu código funcionou muito bem! Só me restou uma duvida: é necessario clicar primeiro no numero do pedido, depois na link que abre o modal. É possivel "unificar" os dois, para que o usuario clique apenas em um link ?

Comment: Possível até é, mas teria que modificar alguma coisa no código do plugin, pra quando ele for abrir o modal executar o `$.ajax` . Veja a documentação do plugin do modal, talvez você ache alguma coisa relacionada a eventos. Mas por enquanto pode usar esse que dará super certo.

Comment: YEAH! Estava na documentação do bootstrap, obrigado!